# Is the modern Latin lexicon productive?

Tags: latin, lexicon, production

So I was wondering, does Latin taught in schools today add/borrow content words to/for its lexicon for things that weren't around (like computer, LED etc.) when Latin was natively spoken? And also, are these words simply borrowed, or do they undergo changes in pronunciation and morphology that one would normally observe in a language that is natively spoken?
Also, does Latin spoken by the Pope add/borrow content words? etc... same questions...

Does this edit clarify what Latin I'm asking about?

Comment: Sure. How could the Pope talk about thermonuclear warfare and the internet in Latin without Latin terms for them? There's an office for that in the Vatican.

Comment: I can't think of any schools where modern Latin is taught.

Comment: If you can precisely define what "modern Latin" is you'll surely immediately find your answer. But what counts as "modern Latin" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: That there are different definitions of modern Latin and different opinions about it doesn't mean this question is "primarily opinion-based", as a close vote suggests. Whether Universal Grammar is an adequate model of human language is also a matter of opinion, but it doesn't mean we can't have a useful debate about it.

Comment: @robert This site is explicitly not about debate. It is about Q&As. Questions need to be well scoped and potentially definitively answered. "Is UG an adequate model?" would be closed. "What arguments do UG supports use?" is a good question. This question needs to be more precise in what it considers "modern Latin".

Comment: This question is better placed on the (new) [latin.se]

Comment: The Vatican Latin Foundation (Fondatum Latinitas) is a body of some accepted authority for suggesting neologisms in Latin to cover modern vocabulary (Like modern technology)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insofar as Linnean binomial nomenclature is in Latin and they are cooking up new names all the time, yes, and apparently it is expanding to galaxies. [Here](http://www.obta.uw.edu.pl/~draco/docs/voccomp.html) is a list of Latin computer terms (English to Latin translation). As with English, there isn't a single pronunciation (< principi > = [printʃipi, printsipi, priŋkipi]), so expect variation. For example, [this newscast](http://www.latinitatis.com/latinitas/audio/nuntii1.htm) is Latin filtered through Finnish phonetics.